# Entity Framework Core How to make a Reference table for a model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have been using SQL tables for referencing static data, for example in one of my apps a technician has a one-to-many relation with a clients table.

Basically what I want to do in SQL is this, so instead of dealing with strings I deal with ints as byte or tinyint which takes less size on disk since Clients are always static and it's rare to add new ones.

```
 | Technicians |    |            Clients              |   | ClientsRef |
 |     Id      |    | Id | ClientRefId | TechnicianId |   | Id  | Name |
```

My problem is to do this in EF Core 2.2, how do I create this static data? I read about using enum but how can I access that data in SQL Server after?

```
public class Technician
{
    int Id { get;set; }
}

public class Client
{
    int Id { get;set; }
    int Technicianid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  If your .NET Classes use 'int', then your SQL Server database will too.  Can you add enough code to your question to explain what you're asking?

Comment: edited, should be more clear

Comment: Just create a class model that looks like the three tables you have. I don't really understand the problem. For EF there's no difference between static data and mutable data. It's just data and it's up to you whether or not you allow an application to modify them.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is that `ClientsRef` is in fact the `Clients` table (each row represents one client) and what you call `Clients` is the association between technicians and clients. It's a classical many-to-many association.

Comment: it is a one to many relation, like i said, the clientsRef table is what you call in english a look up table, static data to save storage by using integers on the real table

Comment: Sure, a `Technician` can "have" `n` clients referring to `n` client-references -- and 1 `Client` has only one `Technician`. But another `Technician` can have the same `n` clients referring to the same `n` client-references. There's a many-to-many relationship between `Technicians` and `ClientsRef`. I only suggest other names, because one record in `Clients` *is* not a client. It merely records an association between a one physical technician and one physical client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
public class Technician
{
    int Id { get;set; }
}

public class Client
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int TechnicianId { get; set; }
    public virtual Technician Technician {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Should be all you need.  There's no need for any other tables or keys in the model.

Comment: Yes but i need to be able to find out which client is associated with each Id, for example Client Id = 1 is Client1,  Id = 2 , is Client2.  Like i said on SQL i have a table with the names associated

Comment: Then add a Name property to the Client entity.

Comment: But then `ClientsRef` and `ClientRefId` are redundant.

Comment: Yep.  Looks redundant to me: `A technician has a one-to-many relation with a clients table`